# New Picklist Values added via Metadata API stay inactive

Tags: apex, metadata-api, picklist, future, dynamic

I am using the `Metadata API` wrapper from https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi to dynamically add picklist values to an existing field.

```
@Future(Callout=true)
private static void updateValueSet(Set<String> newTopics, String fieldName) {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort mdapi = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    mdapi.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    mdapi.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    MetadataService.CustomField fieldMdApi = (MetadataService.CustomField)
            mdapi.readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { fieldName }).getRecords()[0];

    for(MetadataService.CustomValue existingTopic : fieldMdApi.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value) {
        newTopics.add(existingTopic.fullName);
    }

    for(String missing : newTopics) {
        MetadataService.CustomValue value = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
        value.fullName = missing;
        value.default_x = false ;
        value.isActive = true;

        fieldMdApi.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value.add(value);
    }

    mdapi.updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{ fieldMdApi });
}
```

I have found some unclear hint that doing both is not possible in one "go" but I can remember that this once worked. If this indeed doesn't work how could I activate them in a second run? I am already using `@future`.

Comment: As far as I remember, there were certains issues regarding SessionID in the future method. Is that possible that session is not valid at the moment of execution?

Comment: It's creating the new Picklist values but they are not activated. So I think there is no SessionId issue.

Comment: Indeed, session works as expected... I have tried your code and it seems to be working as expected, and picklist values are active under condition that `newTopics` are not changed at line 11 (otherwise it will fail with duplicates because of fieldMdApi.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value already contains given values once)

Comment: @kurunve can you add that as a real answer please. It indeed solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In the given particular scenario, issue might occur due to duplicate values in picklist value set for chosen field.

In case if field is retrieved by MetadataService, it already contains existing active value set definitions (as `fieldMdApi.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value`).

Since salesforce does not allow to have duplicate picklist values, there are no need to add existing picklist values second time to the collection, but rather remove them from `newTopics` in order to guarantee uniqueness.

Following snippet should be working as expected:

```
@future(callout=true)
private static void updateValueSet(Set<String> newTopics, String fieldName) {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort mdapi = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    mdapi.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    mdapi.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    MetadataService.CustomField fieldMdApi = (MetadataService.CustomField)
            mdapi.readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { fieldName }).getRecords()[0];

    for(MetadataService.CustomValue existing : fieldMdApi.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value) {
        if (newTopics.contains(existing.fullName)) {
            newTopics.remove(existing.fullName);
        }
    }

    for(String missing : newTopics) {
        MetadataService.CustomValue value = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
        value.fullName = missing;
        value.default_x = false ;
        value.isActive = true;

        fieldMdApi.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value.add(value);
    }

    mdapi.updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{ fieldMdApi });
}
```

Comment: It's strange this does work in a DX scratch org but in a real org the values (even created by Admin users) stay inactive.

Answer (score 1):

The picklist remains inactive since you have assigned (value.isActive = true) for the picklist, I recommend to use the below piece of code to make the picklist active.

value.isActive = null;

If you want to know the reason behind the assigning as null, use tooling API and hit the custom field URL with your field id as below and maybe you can use the workbench for hitting the below url.

/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N540000071QJG

(Replace your custom field id at last)

When you see the json response, the active picklist value has the inactive field as null.